# SharePoint Foundation 2010 installation fails in Windows Server 2008

Tags: installation, windows-server

Installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 on a Virtual Machine running Windows Server Standard or Windows Server 2008 R2 fails at the end of the installation saying that errors occurred and the log must be consulted etc.

The log wasn't helpful, but I did notice in the %TEMP% directory that there was a folder for SQL Express, so it turns out it was SQL Express part that failed during the setup of the standalone Sharepoint Foundation 2010 installation. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957453

The prerequisites installed fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem as described in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957453
was that the SQL Server Folders in my Program Files and Program Files (x86) were marked as "Allow this folder to be compressed".

So the installation fails because the folders had compression enabled.  Clear the compress attribute on the Microsoft Sql Server folder, and the installation will complete without errors this time.

Answer (score -1):

You can't installed SharePoint 2010 and SQL Server Express for stand-alone installation. Microsoft doesn't support this topology.

Reference resource: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx#topologies

Comment: The link says it is supported.  Thanks for trying!

Comment: Thanks Thuan, but you did refer to the Upgrade requirements, here are the Install requirements: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx it seems Express 2010 is supported.

Comment: Perhaps your definition of Stand-Alone is different to the one's in the documentation, or are you comparing Foundation to normal SP 2010 here?  Please do qualify what you mean rather than repeating? I've installed Foundation stand-alone, it comes with SQL Express 2010.  
http://stovereffect.com/2010/07/07/installing-sharepoint-foundation-2010-stand-alone/
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lv-LV/sharepoint2010setup/thread/08392217-60fb-4e31-9bf4-9afa9300c261
Sorry if the words on this site aren't coming across as they should, sometimes text can miss out the true meaning of things.

Comment: @Thuan the documentation you are referring is saying that in-place upgrade is not supported in a SPS 2010 and SQL Server Express configuration, if you are upgrading from MOSS 2007. The TechNet library installation requirement article, david is referring to, clearly states that SPS 2010 and SQL Server Express in a stand-alone configuration is supported.